# Question about plane quintic

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let the canonical curve $C$ $\subset$ $\mathbb{P}^5$ lie on the Veronese surface. How to see that $C$ is a smooth plane quintic?

Answer (score 2):

If it's on a Veronese surface, the Veronese embedding exhibits it as isomorphic to a smooth plane curve. Since it has degree 10, can't we simply conclude that it is the image of a smooth plane quintic?

Comment: yes, a smooth plane curve of genus 6 is necessarily a quintic.

Answer (score 1):

This is indeed included in the content of **Enriques-Petri theorem**, which you may find it in "*Principles of Algebraic geometry*" by *Griffiths-Harris*, page 535. Its proof is [here](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF01430982?LI=true) (in case you have access to SpringerLink)

Comment: The problem is that the proof of Enriques-Petri theorem in Griffiths-Harris uses this fact.

Answer (score 0):

This has to do with a theorem of Enriques and Petri. For a nonhyperelliptic canonical curve $C$ of genus $g\geq 3$, there are two possibilities: its ideal sheaf may or may not be generated by quadrics, and the theorem says that the second possibility occurs if and only if $C$ is contained in a surface of (minimal) degree $g-2$, if and only if $C$ is either trigonal or (for $g=6$) isomorphic to a smooth plane quintic.

Now, our $C$ is embedded in the Veronese surface (of degree $4=g-2$), and the gonality of $C$ is $[(6+3)/2]=4\neq 3$, so $C$ is isomorphic to a smooth plane quintic.

You can look up at ACGH's *Geometry of Algebraic Curves* (Volume I, around p. 244, but also p. 209) for the details.

Comment: The same problem. We can't refer to this theorem, because its proof uses the fact about plane quintic.

Comment: Can you please explain to me what you mean exactly? It is fun because usually a proof does not use the claim to prove the claim :)